# Cannot produce a document in Greek

Tags: miktex, editors, input-encodings, greek

I have just installed MikTeX 2.9 in my gf's laptop along with Texmaker.
I decided to make a test document to see if everything is working fine.
However, while packages are loaded without any problem, when it comes to write greek in Texmaker, the document is built forever. Note that I use PDFLaTeX.

I also tried with TeXworks but the behaviour is exactly the same.

If I select Greek as main language and type in English, the PDF is produced in *Greeklish* which is an expected behaviour.

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}This is the $1^{st}$ \LaTeX document!\\
    Το πρώτο κείμενο \LaTeX.        
\end{document}
```

I also tried to change the editor's encoding, but the behaviour remains the same. I also have to say that I have just formatted the HDD, so it's like a brand new one!

What could be the problem?

Comment: There is no need of Kerkis. I cancelled the line `\usepackage{kerkis}` and everything works ok!

Answer (score 4):

With `\selectlanguage{english}` you're stating that everything is in English, where Greek characters are not known.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is the first \LaTeX{} document!
\end{otherlanguage*}

Το πρώτο κείμενο \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use superscript “st”: it's a Victorian age usage, which has been revived by some known word processor, but it's ugly and unnecessary. For small numbers use the spelled out version; if you need to say “fortysecond”, you can type

```
42nd
```

which is all is needed. Don't forget also `{}` after `\LaTeX` if you want a space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I used your code, but I don't get what you get... And I don't understand why to use the `otherlanguage` enviroment. On my own system, I actually use `selectlanguage{}` through a command I defined, which is working with no problem. Anyway, my output is http://i.imgur.com/j7GIoHO.png

Comment: Let alone that there are many errors coming up. For every greek letter I get `!Undefined Control Sequence.<argument> \textTau T`...

Comment: @Thanos I can say nothing without seeing the command you're using.

Comment: It seems that `\usepackage{kerkis}` must be after `babel` and `inputenc`... Doing that it works! However, there is another mystery...If I want to edit the `.tex` file, I have to delete every output file and then built again, otherwise it keeps building forever...